# does not exist in the current context c# in my codes

Tags: c#, web, webforms

```
namespace ForumSon.App_Code.DataAccess
{
    public class PostForum
    {
        public static int insertForum(int titleId, string question, string posterName, DateTime datetim)
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;
            using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insertForum", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@titleId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = titleId;
                command.Parameters.Add("@question", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = question;
                command.Parameters.Add("@posterName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = posterName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@datetim", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetim;


                rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            return rowsAffected;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is my `PostForum` class; I try using it in my button click but an error reports that **"it does not exist in the current context"**.

How can I deal with it? I need do a `Forum` project in our website.

I am experiencing this error at line:

`PostForum.insertForum(ctitleId, question, posterName, datetime);`

Comment: What doesn't exist? Is this a compile time issue? You need to give more detail about where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your *button click* is in another assembly, say something like `ForumSon.WebSite`.

When you wan't to use your `PostForum`-class in that web-UI-assembly you'll first have to add reference to your DataAccess-assembly and add a using-directive in your consuming UI-class:

```
using ForumSon.App_Code.DataAccess;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help . I did it after i had some new error i my page at first line "Parser error"      "<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Forum.aspx.cs" Inherits="ForumSon.Forum" %>"  I really dont understand what is happening :)  I am really confused because i am working during 5 hours

Comment: yes but i cause parser erorrs in my pages . I really dont understand

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a new question with more information related to that parse error.